# Bitdefender detected my router trying to exploit my PC. Should I be worried?

Tags: networking, router, security, anti-virus, bitdefender

Recently my Bitdefender AV blocked an attempted exploit to my PC via my routers IP address. Should I be concerned? Could it be that my NMAP intense scan caused this?

Bitdefender exploit protection notification:

[image: Bitdefender exploit protection notification]

My router:

[image: My router]

NMAP scan:

[image: NMAP scan]

Comment: What address? Router LAN? Because if it’s `192.168.8.1` then that could mean something is trying to poke through you network.

Comment: You should probably begin by making sure your router's firmware is updated, that you have a strong password set on it and encryption for your router login, if possible. If you continue to see these, you may want to wipe the router, setting it back to factory defaults, and reconfigure it, setting a different strong password on it. Generally, probes from outside your network should be stopped by the ISP, though if you're paying for a static IP or certain other features allowing easier access into your network from outside, these may be used by attackers.

Comment: Regardless all that, this question does need more information. Details about your network setup, to be specific.